# Why logger service can't be injected in the CompilerPass?

Tags: symfony

I execute this command

```
app/console container:debug | grep logger
```

clearly, there is a service named `logger`:

```
 logger                                                             Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.assetic                                             Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.doctrine                                            Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.event                                               Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.php                                                 Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.profiler                                            Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.request                                             Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.router                                              Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.security                                            Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.templating                                          Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 monolog.logger.translation                                         Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger                                                              
 swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger                    Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger                                                                
 swiftmailer.plugin.messagelogger                                   alias for "swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger"
```

I inject the service using this code:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $clients= $container->findTaggedServiceIds('socket.client');

    foreach ($clients as $id => $tags) {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition($id);
        $definition->addArgument($container->getDefinition('logger'));
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The service definition "logger" does not exist.

If change the `logger` service to `monolog.logger.doctrine`, then everything is fine, what happened with logger service?

Another interesting thing is that  even though  the above way didn't work , it works in in yml, I can inject the `logger` service

```
services:
    etc.socket.server:
        class: %etc.socket.server.class%
        arguments: [@logger, @event_dispatcher, @etc.encoder,@etc.message.client.request]
```

the reason I have to inject the logger service in code , because I have several  `socket.client` services, and they are defined in the code.

#### Update:

I can find the  logger service definition in  appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml :

```
 <service id="logger" class="Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger">
      <argument>app</argument>
      <call method="pushHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="monolog.handler.console"/>
      </call>
      <call method="pushHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="monolog.handler.main"/>
      </call>
      <call method="pushHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="monolog.handler.debug"/>
      </call>
 </service>
```

even though I write a compile pass to inject the logger service , it still doesn't work

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

        $clients = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('micro_pay.socket.client');

        foreach ($clients as $id => $tags) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($id);

             $loggerDefinition=$container->findDefinition('logger');  //$loggerDefinition  is null
//            $definition->addArgument($loggerDefinition);  
        }
    }
```

why the logger service is such special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the reference instead?

```
$definition->addArgument(new Reference('logger'));
```

The definition might not exist yet at this point. You never set the actual definition in your argument, you set a reference to a service.

Comment: thanks,  you are right , I  solved this problem later.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the method `findDefinition` instead of `getDefinition` on ContainerBuilder class as described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).

As Example:

Use this:

```
    $definition->addArgument($container->findDefinition('logger'));
```

instead of this:

```
    $definition->addArgument($container->getDefinition('logger'));
```

The main difference between the two methods is about the resolutions of aliases service

> findDefinition:  The method "unaliases" recursively to return a
>   Definition instance

Further reference in the source code [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/582f4753a343f230fbe18b4e9a0747d48351ddfb/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php).

Hope this help

Comment: the findDefinition method still can't find the logger service , it is very strange

Comment: hi @VidyVideni have you done some upgrade of library meanwhile?

Comment: Your intentions are right but your example is wrong. You should use the Reference class to reference a service in an argument, not set the actual definition.